# Detect an IP address of a Wireless Access Point device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip-address

I have a [Wireless Access Point device](http://www.szedup.com/show.aspx?id=1706), which I am planning to put into BeagleBoard-xM, in order to achieve wireless communication (LAN). However, I can't find it's IP address. I mean, I have to know it's IP address in order to connect with BeagleBoard-xM via a terminal emulator.

For the moment, I have this device connected via Ethernet on my router. My router's setting page shows I have this device connected, but no further information. Is there any way to find the IP address of the Wireless Access Point?

I hope of being understood. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If its connected and assigned an IP by the router, it should show the IP in the DHCP table of the router.

Comment: My mistake. Router's setting page shows no device connected, but status of the Ethernet port is up. DHCP server is enabled. What do I miss?

Comment: The status of the port being `up` just means that there is a link. Not that there is any data being exchanged or any IP has been assigned or even requested. So the device might not even have an IP yet.

Comment: A WiFi client connects to a SSID. When the connection was successful, the client gets an IP-address and knows the access point's IP-address.

Answer (score 0):

An access point will *probably* use one of the following IPs, though it doesn't have to:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.254
```

From Linux, you should be able to do:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up 192.168.0.23
sudo ping 192.168.0.1
```

replace the 192.168.0 in the ifconfig line with the first three digits of the other IPs, and if you get a response, that's your number. The 23 is just a random number between 2 and 240; avoid numbers used on other computers!

As a last resort, use nmap to do a host scan:

```
sudo nmap 192.168.0.*
sudo nmap 192.168.1.*
```

Once identified, the following:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1
```

will enable access to the world through the gateway, should you want. Finally, to get a nameserver (so you can ping "google.com", say) find out the address of your ISP's nameserver and do:

```
sudo echo "nameserver $ISP_DNS" >/etc/resolv.conf
```

The above should be replicable with DHCP but only if the DHCP server on the access pont is running and configured properly!

Comment: Accesspoint is not always the same as default gateway or DHCP server, so these may not work

Answer (score 0):

Type: arp -a (look for the MAC address of your access point, and note its IP address)